# dual Dedekind-infinity may not imply Dedekind-infinite without AC

Tags: set-theory, definition, axiom-of-choice

It is written in wikipedia: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set

It is not provable (in ZF without the AC) that dual Dedekind-infinity implies that A is Dedekind-infinite. (For example, if B is an infinite but Dedekind-finite set, and A is the set of finite one-to-one sequences from B, then "drop the last element" is a surjective but not injective function from A to A, yet A is Dedekind finite.)

A is set of all finite subsets of B. Hence it has to be infinite and of same cardinality as of A. But 'drop the last elemenet' but which element.(For this we need choosing map from [0,n] to elements of A but then it requires AC but then these two definitions become equivalent.)

And why A is Dedekind finite.

Comment: $A$ is a set of finite *sequences*, not of finite subsets, so it makes sense to talk of the last element of any member of $A$: If $s\in A$, then $s=(s_0,\dots,s_n)$ for some $s_i\in B$, and "dropping the last element of $s$" results in the sequence $t_s=(s_0,\dots,s_{n-1})$. (If $n=0$ or if $s=\emptyset$, simply set $t_s=\emptyset$.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo But why A will be Dedekind finite

Comment: Also, $A$ does not have the same cardinality as $B$: The set of tuples of length $1$ is in bijection with $B$ and is a proper subset of $A$. (One needs some amount of choice to verify that if $B$ is infinite, then $A$ and $B$ are equipotent. But $B$ cannot be Dedekind finite in this case.)

Comment: Yes, you need to check that $A$ is Dedekind finite. Prove the contrapositive: Check first that a set $S$ is Dedekind infinite iff there is an injection $f:\mathbb N\to S$. Use that $A$ consists of *injective* tuples to conclude that if we have such an $f:\mathbb N\to A$, then there is an injection $g:\mathbb N\to B$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I have taken A to be set of injective tuples and trying to prove A Dedekind finite. But I am having problem in proving it without some choice. And thanks for pointing out and cardinality of A and B will not be same here since we are not assuming any choice

Comment: This is the first time I hear the term dual Dedekind finite set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila dedekind infinite implies there exist 1-1 but not onto map from A to A. But it implies but not equivalent to there exist onto but not 1-1 map from A to A(without AC) hence definition of dual Dedekind.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There is also something called weakly dedekind. Dedekind infinite implies there exist 1-1 map from N to A. But this implies but not equivalent to there exist onto map from A to N(without AC). Hence definition of weakly dedekind set is for which there exist onto map from A to N.

Comment: @AsafKaragila hence I am worried about if we assume fact:  there exist onto map from A to B implies there exist 1-1 map from B to A. Would it imply AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes, as pointed by Andres in the comments.

1. The claim that for an infinite set $A$, the set $B=\{X\subseteq A\mid X\text{ finite}\}$ has the same cardinality as $A$ requires the axiom of choice. For a Dedekind-finite set this is most certainly false in any case (there's an injection from $A$ into $B$, and this injection is not a surjection. So if $|A|=|B|$, it is impossible that $B$ is Dedekind-finite, so $A$ is not either.)
2. Sets have no linear ordering in most cases. So there's no real meaning to "last element". You can talk about the set of finite sequences, but those are always Dedekind-infinite, since $\{\langle a\rangle,\langle a,a\rangle,\langle a,a,a\rangle,\ldots\}$ is a countably infinite subset.

   However, we can show that the set of *injective* finite sequences is in fact Dedekind-finite, when $A$ is Dedekind-finite.

Now we return to your question, if $A$ is Dedekind-finite, and $S$ is the set of injective finite sequences of $A$, then $B$ is Dedekind-finite, and the operation "remove the last element" is well-defined, because the elements of $B$ are *sequences*, and no choice of ordering is needed.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your comment is saying.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still have no idea what you are saying in the comment. If the answer is not visible, how can you comment on it? If there is a problem with showing parts of the answer, it's a problem on your device, it's neither a problem with my answer nor with the website.

Comment: Yes I got it when Andrews pointed it out. I'll fix it in the question. Actually I am having problem in proving:  set of injective finite sequences is Dedekind-finite, when A is Dedekind-finite.

Comment: For the sequence $a_n$, write $A_n$ as the range of the sequence. Then show that $\bigcup A_n$ is an infinite subset of $A$, and conclude that it is a countable set as the union of *enumerated* sets.

Comment: So you are assuming countable union of finite sets is finite. But in a model where Dedekind finite and finite are not same, will countable union of finite set will still be countable.

Comment: No. I'm assuming nothing. The only use of choice in the fact that the union of countable sets is countable, is in choosing the bijections. Here the $A_n$'s are given with enumerations, so no choice is used.

Comment: I didn't say you using choice. I am saying you are assuming fact: countable union of finite sets is countable. Am I right? And will it hold in such a model

Comment: And I said that I do not assume that at all.

Comment: "⋃An is an infinite subset of A, and conclude that it is a countable set as the union of enumerated sets." Aren't you using this fact here.

Comment: Again, this fact when proved in ZFC only uses the axiom of choice to choose enumerations. Here we have the enumerations so no choice is needed.

Comment: Ok right now got the answer. I usually do such silly mistake