# Are these two definitions of finiteness equivalent?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Def1. Say $X$ is finite, if there isn't a $Y\subsetneq X$ such that $|X|=|Y|$.

Def2. Say $X$ is finite, if for every $f:X\to X$, $f$ is an injection iff $f$ is a surjection.

It can be easily verified that they are both equivalent to the usual definition, that is, $X$ is finite iff $|X|=n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, using axiom of choice. Also, it is known that Def1 is strictly weaker than the usual one in $ZF$. (There is an 'infinite' $X$ which satisfies Def1)

My question is, is Def1=Def2 in $ZF$, and is Def2=the usual one in $ZF$?

Comment: Your first definition is called *Dedekind-finiteness*.

Comment: (If my understanding is correct, then being finite$\to$ finite${}^2\to$  finite$^1$, but the reverse implication does not hold. The Wikipedia page I linked mentioned the proof of finite${}^1\nrightarrow$ finite${}^2$, and the basic Mostowski model witnesses finite$\nrightarrow$finite${}^2$.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila the question is, suppose $X$ is Dedekind finite, and $f:X\to X$ is surjective, is $f$ also injective. Please find a better duplicate.

Comment: @Yuz: Thank you, now it's *very* clear. I will look for a better duplicate. In the meantime, please [edit] your question.

Comment: Will [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454344/does-surjective-infinite-implies-dedekind-infinite) or [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338462/dual-dedekind-infinity-may-not-imply-dedekind-infinite-without-ac) do?

Comment: @AsafKaragila this does.